# Displaced text when importing eps

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab, epstopdf, psfrag, auto-pst-pdf

I have a problem with my MATLAB plots. I need to use `tikz/pgf` created figures and display MATLAB plots where I want the font and fontsize to be equal in all figures even if I change the size of the figure in LaTeX. I tried the following, but I have always at least one problem left, using Texmaker on Windows 7.

1. Use psfrag package for graphic import. Problem is I get `Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`. Anyway pdflatex finishes and everything is okay, just the psfrag plots are not printed. I tried to find a solution but any of the suggested ifpdf variants didn't work. If I use only `psfrag` everything is okay.

Code Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{center}
\psfragfig[width=0.8\textwidth]{images/test.eps}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\node[rectangle, draw] (box) 
{Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Structure of \textit{User Controller}}
\label{fig:UserController}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

More precisely it creates a `*-pics.pdf` file, but its just an empty page. It doesn't create any log file, I just don't know where the problem is. Further it doesn't make a difference if replace the externalization in tikz.

2. Use `.eps` Export in MATLAB and create a pdf_tex with Inkscape.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\include{images/test}
\end{document}
```

I tried it with graphicx, too, but in both cases the same problem, as can be seen in the picture.
[image]
The axes numbering is displaced, the numbers of the y-axis even rotated. I don't understand why this happens, in the eps Original everything is okay.

Another problem of the second trial is, that the use of `\centering` or `\begin{center}` in the figure environment leads to missing `\item` errors I don't understand.

It would be really nice if anybody of you could help me or provide me with another solution how to import MATLAB figures, such that in the end all fonts and fontsizes are suitable.

Thank you very much and please tell me if you need more information.

P.S. Minimal example for graphicx.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,import}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\chapter{test chapter}
\begin{figure}[h!]
%\centering
\import{images/}{test.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(Activating \centering here leads to the reported error.)

Edit: I tried the use of eps2pgf, too, but it throws an error with my graphics ("Type: Feature not (yet) implemented: TexString for /hyphen is unknown")

Edit 2: For all who have a valid MATLAB license, it happens with all my figures, for example create it with

```
plot(1:.1:100, sin(1:.1:100));
xlabel('time');
ylabel('Power');
legend('Power');
```

save it as .eps and convert it with Inkscape.

Edit 3: So now I uploaded the example file: [sinus1.eps](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1C80-VmtYC4TWNTX3h6UldwNjQ)

Comment: Can you upload the `.eps` file and add a link here?

Comment: Is there any webspace here I can use, or do you prefer any service?
If you have a MATLAB license you could just create a figure as I posted in an answer.

Comment: are you sure that MATLAB code is enough? I would think it should need more in otder to generate a `.pdf_tex` file. You can use any service to hold the eps

Comment: More or less. As I wrote I saved the figure in the MATLAB dialogue as `.eps` and worked with that file. The conversion to `.eps_tex` or `.pdf_tex` files was done in inkspace using the appropriate option in the save dialogue.
By the way, I uploaded the `.eps` file and added the link to my post.